# Render multiple widget React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-component

I would like to render widgets in html multiple times.
I have 3 div with the same id, but with different attributes, and I would like to render my react component 3 times on the page. Now I get only the first component.

Html:

```
<div id="myapp" att="1"></div>
<!-- Something else -->
<div id="myapp" att="2"></div>
<!-- Something else -->
<div id="myapp" att="3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js

```
const container = document.getElementById('myapp');
ReactDOM.render(
 <App
  att={container.getAttribute('att')}
 />,
 container,
);
```

Do you have any suggestion how can I render my component three times?

Comment: You can use just one id in a html page and getElementById gives the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your App component would contain the components that you would want to render.

So in App.js you would have something like this, you could pass attributes to the divs using `props`

```
const widgetOne = props => (
  <div att={props.attribute}>
    <h1>WidgetTwo</h1>
  </div>
);

const widgetTwo = props => {
  <div att={props.attribute}>
    <h1>WidgetTwo</h1>
  </div>;
};

const widgetThree = () => {
  <div>
    <h1>WidgetThree</h1>
  </div>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <widgetOne att={1} />
      <widgetTwo att={2} />
      <widgetThree />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Your html would have a `div` that the App component would hook onto like so `<div id="root"></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my final goal is to embed this component in different pages multiple times dynamicaly. So I would like to use those div-s, because it is depending on the parent pages what will be in my component and how many times will be shown.

Comment: Right, you can do that with React. The component is rendering normal html.

Comment: Sorry, I mean different websites, not pages. For example my component is a facebook like button, and I would like to embed it in different websites, for example in a wordpress pages, and I load just my component from my server. My problem is if i put lot of "like buttons" on a page with the same id, i get only the first component.